# parse json data into table with JAVASCRIPT ajax .net

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, vb.net

I want to parse json data into table

in the vb I write

```
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim conn As New SqlConnection()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    conn.ConnectionString = "server=AIONSTUDENT01\SQLEXPRESS;Database=TestDB;User ID=sa;Password=1234;Trusted_Connection=False;"
    conn.Open()
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd = New SqlCommand("select WA01_CNTY_CD,WA01_CNTY_NM_C from WA01", conn)

    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim jason As String = ""
    Dim D As String = ""

    da.Fill(ds, "mytable")

    If ds.Tables("mytable").Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables("mytable").Rows
            Dim a As String = dr("WA01_CNTY_CD")
            Dim b As String = dr("WA01_CNTY_NM_C")

            jason += "{" + """Code"":""" + a.ToString + """," + """countryname"":""" + b.ToString + """}" + ","

                'C += a + ","
                'D += b + ","
            Next

        End If

        Dim jason2 As String = jason.Remove(jason.Length - 1)
        Dim jason3 As String = "[" + jason2 + "]"

        If "" & Request("AJAX") = "1" Then
            Response.Write(jason3)
            Response.End()
            conn.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
```

the output looks is

```
[{"Code":"CN","countryname":"中國"},{"Code":"JP","countryname":"日本"},
 {"Code":"KR","countryname":"韓國"},{"Code":"TW","countryname":"台灣"},
 {"Code":"US","countryname":"美國"},{"Code":"CL","countryname":"阿囉哈"},
 {"Code":"ML","countryname":"馬來西亞"}]
```

and then I  have trouble

```
<title></title>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#button1").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'country.aspx?AJAX=1',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (response) {
                    var json = $.parseJSON(response)
                    var tr;
                    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                        tr = $('<tr/>');
                        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].code + "</td>");
                        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].countryname + "</td>");  
                        $('table').append(tr);
                    }                                                                
                }
            });
         });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>code</th>
        <th>countryname</th>       
    </tr>
</table>
<p/>
<button id="button1">Ajax</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I click the button but nothing happened.

I learn them by myself and my English is poor, so I think there are some ridiculous mistakes .

thank for your assistance

Comment: Are you able to use developer tools in whatever browser you use to see where javascript errors are occurring? Are you sure that the ajax call is successful? What does the javascript object look like after you call `$.parseJSON(response)`?

Comment: Also change `json[i].code` to `json[i].Code `.

Comment: Try to remove `var json = $.parseJSON(response)` maybe jQuery is parsing your response.

Comment: Your code works for me except for the `json[i].code` part that you need to update like @ViktorKukurba said. But I think the src of your jQuery script is suspicious. Do you have an error in your console ?

Comment: Thank you . It's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not append element in loop. Its a bad practice.

You can try something like this:

```js
// Create html string for data received
function createHtmlString(data){
  var result = "";
  data.forEach(function(item){
    result += "<tr>";
    result += "<td>" + item.Code + "</td>";
    result += "<td>" + item.countryname + "</td>";
    result += "</tr>"
  });
  
  return result;
}

function getData(){
  var data = [{"Code":"CN","countryname":"中國"},{"Code":"JP","countryname":"日本"},
 {"Code":"KR","countryname":"韓國"},{"Code":"TW","countryname":"台灣"},
 {"Code":"US","countryname":"美國"},{"Code":"CL","countryname":"阿囉哈"},
 {"Code":"ML","countryname":"馬來西亞"}];

  return data;
}

function appendElement(){
  var data = getData();
  var html = createHtmlString(data);
  
  // Perform bulk operation
  $("#tbl").html(html);
}

appendElement();
```

```css
td{
  border:1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl"></table>
```